# How do I get my backgroundImageView to be draggable instead of main view

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

```
class PhotoViewController: UIViewController {

override var prefersStatusBarHidden: Bool {
    return true
}

private var backgroundImage: UIImage

init(image: UIImage) {
    self.backgroundImage = image
    super.init(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)
    print(image)
}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()


    self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.gray
    let backgroundImageView = UIImageView(frame: view.frame)
    backgroundImageView.image = backgroundImage
    backgroundImageView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true


    let panGestureRecognizer = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(panGestureRecognizerAction(_:)))
    backgroundImageView.addGestureRecognizer(panGestureRecognizer)


    view.addSubview(backgroundImageView)
}




func panGestureRecognizerAction(_ gesture: UIPanGestureRecognizer){
    let translation = gesture.translation(in: view)
    view.frame.origin.y = translation.y

    if gesture.state == .ended{

        let velocity = gesture.velocity(in: view)

        if velocity.y > 1500{
            UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, animations: { 
                self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
            })
        } else{
            UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3, animations: { 

                self.view.frame.origin = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0)
            })
        }
    }
}
```

My entire view moves and reveals a black background behind it. How do i get the backgroundImageView to move instead? I am trying to display a view underneath. If any other info is required please let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `panGestureRecognizerAction` you are asking it to move `view`, which is the `view` of your viewController.  Instead, use the `view` assigned to the gestureRecognizer by saying:

```
if let bgImage = gesture.view {
    bgImage.frame.origin.y = translation.y
}
```

`gesture.view` is an optional, which is why I check it first.  You could also say `gesture.view?.frame.origin.y = translation.y` and that'd work just fine too.

Comment: Works great. Thanks a lot!